# Language in Bootstrap datetimepicker widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker

I'm trying to set up "spanish" language in [Bootstrap datetimepicker widget](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) from [Eonasdan](https://github.com/Eonasdan) according to documentation, just enough do this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
                language: 'es'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

But it doesn't work :\
I have linked the javascript plugin and css (not minified). And also I have changed the default language setup, this is my setup in bootstrap-datetimepicker.js:

```
$.fn.datetimepicker.defaults = {
        pickDate: true,
        pickTime: true,
        useMinutes: true,
        useSeconds: false,
        useCurrent: true,
        minuteStepping: 1,
        minDate: pMoment({y: 1900}),
        maxDate: pMoment().add(100, 'y'),
        showToday: true,
        collapse: true,
        language: 'es',
        defaultDate: '',
        disabledDates: false,
        enabledDates: false,
        icons: {},
        useStrict: false,
        direction: 'auto',
        sideBySide: false,
        daysOfWeekDisabled: false,
        widgetParent: false
    };
```

And I have additionally added the following to the final of this script:

```
$.fn.datetimepicker.dates['es'] = {
        days: ["Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado", "Domingo"],
        daysShort: ["Dom", "Lun", "Mar", "Mie", "Jue", "Vie", "Sab", "Dom"],
        daysMin: ["Do", "Lu", "Ma", "Mi", "Ju", "Vi", "Sa", "Do"],
        months: ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"],
        monthsShort: ["Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic"],
        today: "Hoy"
        };
```

And my code is:

```
$(function () {
    $('#fechanac').datetimepicker({
        pickTime: false,
        language: 'es'
    });
});
```

Anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks for reading!

Comment: You need to include `es.js`

Comment: Thanks for commente, but, where I can find that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well see http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#using-locales this page also tells you:

> Note that the language file must be included from the locales folder

Than read the page at https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/wiki/Installation under minimal requirements you can read:

> Locales: Moment's locale files are [here](https://github.com/moment/moment/tree/develop/locale)